# How to use SUM(CASE WHEN....) in JPQL Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpql

I have the following query:

```
Query qQuery = entityManager.createQuery("select " +
                "    sum((case when mt.prop1 = true then 1 else 0 end)), " +
                "    sum((case when mt.prop2 = true then 1 else 0 end)), " +
                "    sum((case when mt.prop3 = false then 1 else 0 end)), " +
                "    sum((case when mt.prop3 = true then 1 else 0 end)) " +
                "from MyTable mt " +
                "where mt.id = :myId ");
```

However, this throws a syntax error on the query when I put a case statement inside an aggregate.

I can get SUM to work fine alone, and case statements to work fine alone. I'm wondering whether JPQL can support cases in aggregates or if I'm forced to use a native query.

Comment: One possible workaround here would be to first subquery and generate the `CASE` expressions, then sum the aliases.  However, HQL does not support subqueries, either, AFAIK.  Yes, you might need to use a native query here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh..... false alarm. IntelliJ is just stupid. I just ran the query and it's fine. IntelliJ still shows the error but it works.

To anyone who comes across this issue.... just run it before you jump to conclusions, even with the error prompt by IntelliJ or other IDE. Sometimes the IDE is just wrong.